# Parse & Pubnub for image messaging chat appllcation

Tags: android, image, mobile, parse-platform, pubnub

We are developing a real time android chat application that will support text and image messaging. It will also sort other users based on their location and proximity to the user. Is using pubnub and parse a viable solution?

How can we implement sending image messages using Pubnub? Also, can we use firebase for the same? Which one is a better solution in terms of development effort, cost & scalability?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Parse & PubNub for Location Based Image Messaging and Chat

Here are a few resources that will help you get started with PubNub and Parse for Location Based Image Messaging and Chat.  Note that we have an officially supported PubNub Parse Cloud Code SDK to help simplify your integration needs.

> [Location based Geohashing Chat by User Proximity  `tutorial`](http://www.pubnub.com/blog/geohashing-chat-by-proximity/)

1. [Realtime Collaboration Sync with Parse API and PubNub `tutorial`](http://www.pubnub.com/blog/realtime-collaboration-sync-parse-api-pubnub/)
2. [How do I publish a message from Parse?  `community`](https://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/discussion/293/how-do-i-publish-a-message-from-parse)
3. [PubNub JavaScript SDK for Parse.com CloudCode platform `beta`](https://github.com/pubnub/javascript/tree/add-parse-support/parse)

Comment: I'm trying to implement a chat app but I can't find anything regarding the sending of images/videos over pubnub

Comment: Check this [Create a Realtime Raspberry Pi Security Camera w/ Parse](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-06-30-create-realtime-raspberry-pi-security-camera-w-parse/) shows you how to send images.

Comment: Thanks I saw it, so for android I should use the same way? Is there any android sample code for uploading images?

Comment: You'll want to refer to Parse HTTP REST guide here: [Android save File Image](https://www.parse.com/questions/android-save-file-image) and [Android Parse.com Image Upload Tutorial](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parse-com-image-upload-tutorial/)

Comment: Cool, so I have to use Parse for that as my back-end storage right, thanks for the quick reply!